# How to confirm a multisig ETC contract wallet transaction that requires two account signers?

Tags: ethereum-classic, multisignature

I created a multisig contract wallet with Ethereum Wallet that requires two signatures well before the ETH/ETC hard fork. I'm just now coming back to try and move my ETC out of the 2sig contract wallet, but can't seem figure out how to confirm the transaction from the second signature account? Preferably looking for a solution that uses Parity or MyEtherWallet and not much code/command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! Turns out to be fairly simple and fast. Just need to run [Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases) in ETC mode (Target = "C:\Program Files\Parity\Parity\parity.exe" --chain=classic --geth), wait for it to sync, and then use the standard [Ethereum Wallet (Mist)](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) on top of that. The Ethereum wallet connects to the Geth that Parity is using and since it is in ETC mode, Ethereum Wallet is transacting on your ETC. Easy Peasy. This YouTube video shows how to do it well: youtube.com/watch?v=peAnJ3rRn04